# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException on changing spring-data-neo4j version to 4.0.0.RELEASE

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j-4, spring-data-redis

I am using three databases: Redis, Neo4j and Mongodb. All my apis were working fine until I changed the version of spring-data-neo4j from 3.3.2.RELEASE to 4.0.0.RELEASE. There is no change in the versions of spring-data-mongodb: 1.8.0.RELEASE and spring-data-redis:1.4.3.RELEASE.

On changing the version of spring-data-neo4j to 4.0.0.RELEASE and completing the required migration process, I am getting this error:

```
    [DEBUG] com.movements.jhipster.Application - Running with Spring Boot v1.2.6.RELEASE, Spring v4.1.7.RELEASE
    [DEBUG] com.movements.jhipster.config.AsyncConfiguration - Creating Async Task Executor
    [DEBUG] com.movements.jhipster.config.MetricsConfiguration - Registering JVM gauges
    [INFO] com.movements.jhipster.config.MetricsConfiguration - Initializing Metrics JMX reporting
    [DEBUG] com.movements.jhipster.config.MailConfiguration - Configuring mail server
    [INFO] com.movements.jhipster.Application - Running with Spring profile(s) : [dev]
    [INFO] com.movements.jhipster.config.WebConfigurer - Web application configuration, using profiles: [dev]
    [DEBUG] com.movements.jhipster.config.WebConfigurer - Initializing Metrics registries
    [DEBUG] com.movements.jhipster.config.WebConfigurer - Registering Metrics Filter
    [DEBUG] com.movements.jhipster.config.WebConfigurer - Registering Metrics Servlet
    [INFO] com.movements.jhipster.config.WebConfigurer - Web application fully configured
    [WARN] org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'feedRedisRepository': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.movements.jhipster.redis.repository.base.ISortedSetRepository com.movements.jhipster.redis.repository.FeedRedisRepository.repoZSet; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.movements.jhipster.redis.repository.base.ISortedSetRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:687) [spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321) [spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
        at com.movements.jhipster.Application.main(Application.java:72) [bin/:na]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.movements.jhipster.redis.repository.base.ISortedSetRepository com.movements.jhipster.redis.repository.FeedRedisRepository.repoZSet; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.movements.jhipster.redis.repository.base.ISortedSetRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        ... 14 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.movements.jhipster.redis.repository.base.ISortedSetRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
    [INFO] com.movements.jhipster.config.CacheConfiguration - Closing Cache Manager
    [WARN] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' is defined)
    [ERROR] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'feedRedisRepository': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.movements.jhipster.redis.repository.base.ISortedSetRepository com.movements.jhipster.redis.repository.FeedRedisRepository.repoZSet; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.movements.jhipster.redis.repository.base.ISortedSetRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:687) ~[spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321) ~[spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.movements.jhipster.Application.main(Application.java:72) [bin/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.movements.jhipster.redis.repository.base.ISortedSetRepository com.movements.jhipster.redis.repository.FeedRedisRepository.repoZSet; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.movements.jhipster.redis.repository.base.ISortedSetRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.movements.jhipster.redis.repository.base.ISortedSetRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'feedRedisRepository': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.movements.jhipster.redis.repository.base.ISortedSetRepository com.movements.jhipster.redis.repository.FeedRedisRepository.repoZSet; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.movements.jhipster.redis.repository.base.ISortedSetRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:687)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at com.movements.jhipster.Application.main(Application.java:72)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.movements.jhipster.redis.repository.base.ISortedSetRepository com.movements.jhipster.redis.repository.FeedRedisRepository.repoZSet; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.movements.jhipster.redis.repository.base.ISortedSetRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.movements.jhipster.redis.repository.base.ISortedSetRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 16 more
Exception in thread "Thread-13" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Shutdown in progress
    at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.add(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:66)
    at java.lang.Runtime.addShutdownHook(Runtime.java:211)
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.io.file.FileCleaner.forceDeleteOnExit(FileCleaner.java:49)
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.io.file.Files.forceDelete(Files.java:119)
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.store.ArtifactStore.removeFileSet(ArtifactStore.java:91)
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.store.CachingArtifactStore$FilesWithCounter.forceDelete(CachingArtifactStore.java:151)
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.store.CachingArtifactStore.removeAll(CachingArtifactStore.java:94)
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.store.CachingArtifactStore$CacheCleaner.run(CachingArtifactStore.java:171)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
failed
```

ISortedSetRepository.java is as follows:

```
@Repository
public class  ISortedSetRepository<String, V> implements ISortedSet<String, V>{

    @Autowired 
    @Qualifier("redisTemplate")
    private RedisTemplate<String,V> redisTemplate;


    @Override
    public void add(String key, V value, double score) {
        redisTemplate.opsForZSet().add(key, value, score);

    }

    @Override
    public void multiAdd(String key, Set<TypedTuple<V>> tuples) {       

        redisTemplate.opsForZSet().add(key, tuples);

    }

    @Override
    public Collection<V> get(String key, long start, long end) {
        return redisTemplate.opsForZSet().reverseRange(key,start,end);
    }


    @Override
    public Long remove(String key, V value) {
        return redisTemplate.opsForZSet().remove(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAll(String key) {
        redisTemplate.delete(key);
    }



    @Override
    public Long size(String key) {
        return redisTemplate.opsForZSet().size(key);
    }

    @Override
    public Double incrementScore(String key, V value, double delta) {
        return  redisTemplate.opsForZSet().incrementScore(key, value, delta);

    }

    @Override
    public Long rank(String key, Object o) {
        return redisTemplate.opsForZSet().rank(key, o);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<V> range(String key, long start, long end) {
        return redisTemplate.opsForZSet().range(key, start, end);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<V> rangeByScore(String key, long min, long max) {
        redisTemplate.opsForZSet().rangeByScore(key, min, max);
        return null;
    }



}
```

RedisConfiguration is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.movements.jhipster.redis")
public class DatabaseConfigurationRedis {

    @Bean
    public RedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
        poolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        poolConfig.setTestOnReturn(true);
        JedisConnectionFactory ob = new JedisConnectionFactory(poolConfig);
        ob.setUsePool(true);
        ob.setHostName("localhost");
        ob.setPort(6379);
        return ob; 
    }
    @Bean(name="redisTemplate")
    public <String,V> RedisTemplate<String,V> redisTemplate(){
        //return new StringRedisTemplate(jedisConnectionFactory());
        RedisTemplate<String,V> redisTemplate =  new RedisTemplate<String, V>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());

        return redisTemplate;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It worked by just changing annotation of @Repository on ISortedSetRepository to @Service.

Answer (score 0):

I was using @Cacheable annotation without giving any concrete implementation and as per https://auth0.com/blog/spring-boot-caching-101/ it should use in-memory cache. The removal of the above annotation helped me get around the above exception